# Wordpress menu style

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am having some difficulty styling the Wordpress menu and to behave how I want it to.

So I am using the following to display my menu:

```
<nav>


    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>



    <br />

    <form method="get" id="search_form" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>"/>
        <input type="text" class="text searchForm" name="s" value="Search" >
    </form>

</nav>
```

Here is the style:

```
   nav li { 
   background-color: #99D9F3;
   margin-bottom: 2px;
   padding: 0; 
   font-weight: 300;
   }


nav a {
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px; /* you can apply padding to the anchor tags instead */
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
    }


.sub-menu{background-color: #fff;}


.sub-menu li {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
}

.sub-menu li:hover{
    border-left: 2px solid orange;
}

.sub-menu a{color:#aaa;}
.sub-menu a:hover{color:#000; font-weight: 500;}
```

This is all well and good apart from a few things, only the text is clickable where as I need the whole `<li>` to be a clickable area. Also, when adding sub items to the menu it stretches out the `<li>` tag from the menu item they sit under, I need a way to hide those too until the item is clicked on and it then shows the sub menu items.

Comment: `form` is not a self-closing element, remove the `/` from the end of  `action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>"/>`

Comment: @DannyHearnah Cheers for spotting that, it wasn't affecting it but its good to make sure there is no typos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use padding for the list items. Also you need to set the property value of your anchor tags display to inline-block or block.

```
display:inline-block; 

/* Or just */

display:block;
```

**See the chnages below**

```
   nav li { 
   background-color: #99D9F3;
   margin-bottom: 2px;
   padding: 0; 
   font-weight: 300;
   }



    nav a {
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px; /* you can apply padding to the anchor tags instead */
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I have made a slight change to the html now, ill update the question for you to see.

Comment: The only other query I have now is, in my question I asked about allowing the whole <li> to be clickable, is there a way around that?

Comment: Do the above and the whole li will be clickable.

Comment: I dosnt appear to be the case for me, I will update my question again to see where I am possibly going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/

You can use superfish menu jquery.. It will help you

Comment: Is there no way you can alter the default WP without using something like superfish?

Comment: @user3328557 you can alter that of WordPress as much as you want.